Please answer me… ‘The only thing which…’ Is it impossible?

The movements themselves are not the only thing which can vary across cultures.

Can't 'which' be used in this sentence?

This question is similar to: When to use “that” and when to use “which”, especially in relative clauses. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. // Another issue here is the conflict of 'are' + 'the only thing'. But agreement between subject and verb is the only grammatical constraint ('are' 'the only thing which/that can vary') can be quite acceptable.

... See tchrist's answer at subject-complement agreement: 'the thing is/are the dangers involved for subject-verb-complement agreements.
